# Typeahead Talent Buddy

Tags: python, optimization, performance, programming-challenge, search

Problem is [Talent Buddy](http://www.talentbuddy.co/challenge/5233cc274af0110af382f4105233cc274af0110af382f40e).

Your task is to

> - write a function that prints to the standard output (stdout) for each query the user name that matches the query
> - if there are multiple user names matching the query please select the one that is the smallest lexicographically
> - all string matches must be case insensitive
> - if no match is found for a given query please print "-1"
>
> **Note that your function will receive the following arguments:**
>
> *usernames*
>    - which is an array of strings representing the user names
>
> *queries*
>    - which is an array of strings representing the queries described above
>
> **Data constraints**
>    - the length of the array above will not exceed 100,000 entries
>    - each name or query string will not exceed 30 characters
>
> **Efficiency constraints**
>
> - your function is expected to print the requested result and return in less than 2 seconds
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Input 
> names: ["james", "jBlank"]
> queries: ["j", "jm", "jbl", "JB"]
>
> Output
> james
> -1
> jBlank
> jBlank
> ```

The above is an example testcase.

My algorithm:

```python
def typeahead(usernames, queries):
        from bisect import bisect_left
        wordlist=sorted(usernames,key=str.lower)
        l_wordlist=map(str.lower,wordlist)
        for i in queries:
            word_fragment=i.lower()
            k=wordlist[bisect_left(l_wordlist, word_fragment): bisect_left(l_wordlist, word_fragment[:-1] + chr(ord(word_fragment[-1])+1))][:1]
            print k[0] if k else  -1
```

Steps:

1. Sorted the usernames lexicographically
2. sorted usernames of small letters(this used in bisect)
3. using word_fragment i am bisecting the total array

When I profiled my method, I got [this testcase](http://tb-eval1.talentbuddy.co/53a02224a2f4e70c0900019933922894345596432000.html):

> ```
>          250005 function calls in 0.715 seconds
>
>    Ordered by: standard name
>
>    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
>         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 bisect.py:1(<module>)
>         1    0.480    0.480    0.715    0.715 py1.py:24(typeahead)
>    100000    0.146    0.000    0.146    0.000 {_bisect.bisect_left}
>     50000    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {chr}
>         1    0.010    0.010    0.010    0.010 {map}
>         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
>     50000    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
>     50000    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {ord}
>         1    0.050    0.050    0.050    0.050 {sorted}
> ```

The problem is that when I run it in the Talent Buddy, it is showing that it takes more than 2 seconds. How can I further optimise my code?

Edit as reference with [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54480/typeahead-autocomplete-functionality-challenge/54483#54483) with [this testcase](http://tb-eval1.talentbuddy.co/53a02224a2f4e70c0900019933922894345596432000.html). The efficient code provided took the below time:

> ```
>         147936037 function calls in 52.394 seconds
>
>    Ordered by: standard name
>
>    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
>         1    0.002    0.002    0.002    0.002 collections.py:1(<module>)
>         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:26(OrderedDict)
>         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:381(Counter)
>         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 heapq.py:31(<module>)
>         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 keyword.py:11(<module>)
>         1   27.895   27.895   52.394   52.394 py.py:24(typeahead)
>    100000    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
>         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
>         1    0.002    0.002    0.002    0.002 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
>    100000    0.025    0.000    0.025    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
> 147736029   24.457    0.000   24.457    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
> ```

Comment: Not sure if this can help you but there is another question about this problem in Python too : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54480/typeahead-autocomplete-functionality-challenge/54483#54483

Comment: *"can any one suggest different paradigm solving the problem"*  - yes, in exactly that post @Josay just linked to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have edited my question. i feel my approach is faster than OP in that link. more over there are repeated iterations in the solution causing it slower than me

Comment: @sundarnataraj: Have you [timed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) them to see which is faster? Have you [profiled](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/profile.html) your code to see where the bottlenecks are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def typeahead(usernames, queries):
        from bisect import bisect_left
        wordlist=sorted(usernames,key=str.lower)
        l_wordlist=map(str.lower,wordlist)
        for i in queries:
            word_fragment=i.lower()
            x=bisect_left(l_wordlist, word_fragment)
            try:
                if word_fragment in l_wordlist[x]:
                    print wordlist[x]
                else: print -1                    
            except: print -1
```

i have increased it performance by

```
k=wordlist[bisect_left(l_wordlist, word_fragment): bisect_left(l_wordlist, word_fragment[:-1] + chr(ord(word_fragment[-1])+1))][:1]
```

there are two bisects functions in above by removing one and converting to below

```
            x=bisect_left(l_wordlist, word_fragment)
            try:
                if word_fragment in l_wordlist[x]:
                    print wordlist[x]
                else: print -1                    
            except: print -1
```

by profiling

```
 100004 function calls in 0.542 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.329    0.329    0.542    0.542 reducer.py:21(typeahead)
    50000    0.116    0.000    0.116    0.000 {_bisect.bisect_left}
        1    0.013    0.013    0.013    0.013 {map}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    50000    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.063    0.063    0.063    0.063 {sorted}
```

reduced the system calls by half from 250005 to 100004 did the magic :)